# How to read the exact command executed by the shell when sent from vim?

Tags: command-line, terminal

Sometimes, when I send a shell command from vim, I receive an error.

For example, when I type the following command `:!chmod +x shellescape("%")`, zsh complains with :

```
zsh:1: unknown sort specifier

shell returned 1
```

I know a way to fix this specific problem :

```
:execute "!chmod +x " . shellescape("%")
```

What I don't know is how to read the exact command that the shell tried to execute when I make a mistake.

The last commands are not sent directly to the shell, vim evaluates a few things before doing so. I would like to see the result of this evaluation.

I tried looking at the output of the `history` command in zsh but it seems that the commands typed in vim are not logged there.

Comment: set the 'verbose' option to 5 before executing a shell command.

Answer (score 2):

A bigger problem here is that your command is wrong.

> :!chmod +x shellescape("%")

What makes you think you can run Vim functions like this? Use [`%:S`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%25%3aS) to escape special shell characters, eg:

```
:!chmod +x %:S
```

I realize this doesn't answer your question directly, but for all practical purposes all you need to know "If error, use `%:S`, if still error, read what you typed", as there aren't any other substitutions done in the `:!` command.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I agree my example was poorly chosen. There's a very good reason why I used it though (for testing and understanding a few things). But in fact the errors I come across are given by other more complex shell commands that I still haven't understood. For example, I would like to populate a local arglist with the output of a shell command (a `find` command with a wildcard). It should be possible. There are even examples given in the help (`:help backtick-expansion`), but on my system they don't work. I've got the error `E79`.

Comment: I need to see what it sends exactly to understand where the problem comes from. I hope the answer of Christian Brabandt will help me. I didn't want to use this more complex shell command as an example because this is a separate problem, I will open a new topic for it if I can't find an answer on my own. Thank you again for your answer, I didn't know the `:S` filename modifier, I'll use it from now on.

Comment: Well, in fact, you are completely right, my problem doesn't come from the shell but from vim itself. `E79` is not a shell error, sorry I made another mistake.

Comment: @saginaw The `:S` modifier is a relatively recent addition to Vim, so depending on your portability requirements, it may be safer to stick with `:exe` and `shellescape()`.

Comment: @jamessan I didn't know that, thank you. Besides, `shellescape()` (for shell arguments) and `fnamescape()` (for vim commands arguments) stick together better in my memory than `:S` and `fnameescape()`.